# I m trying to work with dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker. Daterange picker did not open?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, daterangepicker

I m trying to work with dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker. Daterange picker did not open?
I just put example code to try that. But it did't. What is the wrong part?

```
 $(function() {  
    $('#reservationtime').daterangepicker({ 
        timePicker: true, 
        timePickerIncrement: 30, 
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A' 
    });
});
```

Fiddle is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/nle41/skwjo689/

Comment: you have an error `moment is not a function` are you loading `moment.js` correctly?

Comment: I think so. I added to jsfiddle (on the left part)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load moment.js ***before*** loading daterangepicker.js.

Separately, you have a syntax error in your enclosing function declaration.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/skwjo689/1/

```
$('#reservationtime').daterangepicker({ timePicker: true, timePickerIncrement: 30, format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A' });
```

Be sure to open your brower's console window to get information about any errors that might be occurring, and considering posting error information with future questions.

Comment: Thanks  @kaliatech. And another question is: Can I make it openable when user clicked from or to input field. I want to see datepicker only when I clicked to inputs.

Comment: @Kle. Glad to have helped. Please mark my answer as 'accepted' so others don't have to waste time looking at your question.  Regarding your next question, SO is not a good medium for back-and-forth. I would suggest trying to figure it out on your own, and then if stuck, post a new question. Be sure to specify what you have tried, and include the exact error/problem you are running in to.